# Can not running application with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

I have defined a simple class that looking like this

```
public class Spring1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

     }
}
```

And my configuration file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

When i run the application it shows the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:164)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at project.on.spring.Spring1.main(Spring1.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

Please help me where i have made mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not included "apache commons logging jar". [Download](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) and add it to your project

Answer (score 2):

Donwload [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) and place the jar(s) in WEB-INF/lib.Spring framework come with a lot of libraries. Make sure you have added all the required ones in your class path.

And for the future - google the class name that is not found to see which library it belongs to, download it and put it on the classpath.

Answer (score -1):

`org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` is not compatible with your Spring version.

Download the `JAR`